# full-size background image doesn't show up

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to set a full-size background image using CSS and here is what my code looks like after reading several blogs, including one topic started here on this website:

```
    html{
    background-image: url('C:\Users\sony\Desktop\psddesigns\background.jpeg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
        min-height: 100%; 
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    }
```

The image still doesn't show up. Its size is 2.4 megabytes. All files are on my pc.

Comment: You shouldn't use a file system path in your CSS/HTML code. Try using a relative path instead.

Comment: in addition to the relative path to your file (or using the protocol file:///) you should think about the filesize! 2.4 mb will load really really slow and you don't need a file that is that large. common users will have 1600px width at most so your file doesn't have to be large. And if it browser window is larger, cover will do the job for you

Answer (score 0):

put the css not on the html tag but on the body

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(../images/background/australia_sky.jpg); //this is a relative path change it to your liking
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Comment: doesn't matter at all

Answer (score 0):

use relative url ,eg( url(./psddesigns/background.jpeg) ) or upload it to the internet

Answer (score 0):

Use relative path. Put your HTML file and the image in the same directory and then you can load the image using the relative URL like this:

```
 html {
    background-image: url('image-name.jpeg');
```

There are more you can learn about relative and absolute paths. 
http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm